# How to insert transformed data in a block back into original table?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am pretty sure this question would have been asked before, but I can't find the answer as I don't know what terms I should be searching for.

I have a table:

```
create table tmp_test (
    id serial primary key,
    value integer,
    value_2 numeric
);
```

Initially we may find the following entries in the table:

```
id    value    value_2
______________________
1     4        NULL 
2     3        NULL
3     5        NULL
...
```

I have extracted the first two columns, and done a transformation to obtain the third column, and now I want to update `tmp_table` so that it looks like this:

```
id    value    value_2
______________________
1     4        5.2
2     3        1.3
3     5        2.1
...
```

Is there a way to do it all at once, instead of looping through the rows and executing statements like:

```
update tmp_table set value_2 = 5.2 where id = 1 and value = 4;
```

Comment: What is the transformation? Can be expressed in SQL? If so, you can just adjust my answer to use that transformation in the place of `value_1 / 2.0`

Comment: @Alex how do you determine the `value_2` from `value`? Is it probably stored somewhere else or uses data you haven't provided here? Please edit your question with details.

Comment: @redneb I agree that your answer shows that we can do it within the database itself depending on the transformation. However, the transformation is difficult to express in SQL. I am doing it elsewhere in `R`. @KamilG, It essentially is a complicated cumulative count of items ordered, grouped  by items, taking into account cancelled orders. The transformation is not my focus here. What I want to do is to directly write the populated column `value_2` back into the table.

Comment: @Alex If it can be expressed in SQL, you'll have to do the row-by-row thing. You might be able to process them in batches by it would not make a huge difference. If the transformation depends exclusively on data that exists somewhere in the database (this or other tables), then it is quite likely that it can expressed in SQL.

Comment: Right, so it looks like in the most general case I will have to do the row by row thing. Here is an example where I do not believe that it can be expressed in SQL: suppose we have columns in one table `y` and `x_1`, `x_2`, `x_3`, ... Using a random forest I model the relationship between the `x_i` columns and `y`. Then using this random forest, I make a prediction for what `y` should be. Then, a typical use case would be to write a new column `yhat` containing these predictions back to the database. Maybe it is just easy to deploy a new table with these predictions and link it to the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to insert a set of numbers calculated in your application into the column `value_2`. 
Use two arrays, one for `ids` and another for `values`:

```
select
    unnest(array[1, 2, 3]) id,
    unnest(array[5.2, 1.3, 2.1]) as value

 id | value 
----+-------
  1 |   5.2
  2 |   1.3
  3 |   2.1
(3 rows)
```

Use the primary key to identify the values and update the table using the above query:

```
update tmp_test t
set value_2 = n.val
from (
    select
        unnest(array[1, 2, 3]) id,
        unnest(array[5.2, 1.3, 2.1]) as val
    ) n
where t.id = n.id;
select * from tmp_test;

 id | value | value_2 
----+-------+---------
  1 |     4 |     5.2
  2 |     3 |     1.3
  3 |     5 |     2.1
(3 rows)
```

Comment: thanks, and if there are more than one `id` column, do you extend the where clause to: `where t.id_1 = n.id_1 and t.id_2 = n.id_2`?

Comment: You do not need this as `ids` unambiguously identify appropriate rows.

Comment: but, in a different example with a multi-column key, I would use the where clause in the same way?

Comment: Yes, you should use additional arrays then. However, it is really worth to have one-column numeric primary key in each table.

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
update tmp_table set value_2 = value_1 / 2.0;
```

This will update all rows at once (because there is no `where` clause). Also notice that in the right hand side of the assignment for `value_2` we are allowed to reference other columns (column `value_1` in this case).

Comment: thanks, but this fails in a more general case where the second column is not obtained so simply. I will edit the original post to reflect this, my apologies!